# Regular Expression inner Digits check

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, regular-language

I have the following regex but it fails (the inner digits with the points) :

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.?[0-9]{1,3}\.?[0-9]{1,3})
```

I want that it covers the following cases:

- 123 valid
- 123.4 valid
- 123.44 valid
- 123.445 valid
- 123.**33**.3 not ok (regex validates it as true)
- 123.**3**.3 not ok (regex validates it as true)
- 123.333.3 valid
- 123.333.34 valid
- 123.333.344 valid

Can you please help me?

Comment: Why are `123.33.3` and `123.3.3` not OK? Well, if the second number in a 3-number string should have 3 digits, try [`s.matches("[0-9]{1,3}(?:\\.[0-9]{3})?(?:\\.[0-9]{1,3})?")`](https://regex101.com/r/rKOukX/1)

Comment: I posted [an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458746/3832970).

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: yes all your anwsers did work! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple case, I would like to use `|` the or operator like this :

```
^([0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{1,3})$
^           ^                      ^                                 ^
```

you can check the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/KjcW2I/1)

---

## details

The regex match three cases :

**case 1**

```
[0-9]{1,3}
```

this will match one or more digit

**case 2**

```
[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

this will match one or more digit followed by a dot then one or more digits

**case 3**

```
[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

this will match one or more digit followed by a dot then **three digits** then a dot then one or three digits

Note you can replace `[0-9]` with just `\d` your regex can be :

```
^(\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3})$
```

Comment: thats exactly what I needed! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Wow you are good with regex! I am really bad and a dummy.... Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

How about this one (demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xSOMsM/1)). It's pretty short and straightforward Regex:

```
(^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3}$)|(^\d{3}\.\d{1,3}$)|(^\d{3}$)
```

This recognizes three valid separate groups.

- `(^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{1,3}$)` as a group which must have 3 digits, a dot, 3 more digits, a dot and 1-3 digits.
- `(^\d{3}\.\d{1,3}$)` as a group which must have 3 digits, a dot and 1-3 digits.
- `(^\d{3}$)` as a group which must have 1-3 digits.

These groups split with the **or** (`|`) statement.

However, since you have tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java), why don't let Java to take some responsibility and help Regex where isn't strong? I would rather match the format `((?:\d{1,3}\.?)+)` and check programmatically whether the count of numbers is valid.

Comment: thats also what I needed! Thank you for your great help and for the demo. I am using this regex with my java code and I thought I just write a "simple" (xaxaxa) regex. I usually use other methods (substring etc)... mostly because I am bad with regex...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following expression with `.matches`:

```
s.matches("\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{3})?(?:\\.\\d{1,3})?")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8690lb/1)

**Details**

- `^` - implicit, not necessary as the pattern is used in `.matches` that requires a full string match
- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{3})?` - an optional `.` and 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,3})?` - an optional sequence of `.` and 1 to 3 digits
- `$` - implicit, not necessary since the pattern is used in `.matches` that requires a full string match